# Leaflet-Image() and Leaflet.print() not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm trying to access a map webservice online. I want to export a map as a png ou jpg image.

I managed to display an online map with OSM. I followed instructions [here](https://github.com/g07kore/Web-Mapping-Leaflet-NodeJS-Tutorials#001-leaflet-base-layers). The next step is to save or export the map into an image. 
I found [this](https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.print) and [this](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image), and I tried both.

No need to say, it doesn't work. In fact I think the problem comes from me, I don't think I understood correctly how to use these functions.

Regarding Leaflet-Image(), I tried the following code :

```
leafletImage(map, function(err, canvas) {
// now you have canvas
// example thing to do with that canvas:
var img = document.createElement('img');
var dimensions = map.getSize();

console.log('dimensions :');
console.log(dimensions);

img.width = dimensions.x;
img.height = dimensions.y;
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
document.getElementById('images').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('images').appendChild(img);});
```

An I got this error :

```
leaflet-image.js:87 Uncaught TypeError: layer._adjustTilePoint is not a function
```

The code seems strange to me. My goal is to export the map as an image, in the folder I wish. But I don't give a filepath or a filename...

Regarding leaflet.print(), I tried this :

```
var printProvider = L.print.provider({
method: 'GET',

outputFormat : '.png',
outputFilename: 'Desktop/carte',
autoLoad: true,
dpi: 90

});

var printControl = L.control.print({
   provider: printProvider
});        
map.addControl(printControl);
```

Honestly, I'm completely lost here. So if anyone had an idea or could explain to me how this works, that would be a great help.

Comment: What are your versions of Leaflet and Leaflet-Image ?

Comment: leaflet is 1.3.1 and leaflet-image is 0.4.0 according to package.json

Comment: I'm looking at https://unpkg.com/leaflet-image@0.4.0/index.js , and line 87 does **not** refer to `_adjustTilePoint`. Double-check your version of leaflet-image.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I managed to access the image using its online path (http//...). Depending on the source, it may lead to an access problem, but it works fine with the online mapping service and the provided key. I am not using leaflet at all.

Thanks for the help !